# R leaflet using addWMSTiles

Tags: r, leaflet, wms

I'm trying to add WMS tiles in the R leaflet package,This is an example I found, but it doesn't work
How can I modify it?

```
leaflet() %>%
  addWMSTiles("http://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/geoserver/wms",
              layers = "gpw-v3:gpw-v3-population-density_2000",
              options = WMSTileOptions(format = "image/png", transparent = TRUE) )
```

This is the code I've tried successfully

```
leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>%
  setView(-93.65, 42.0285, zoom = 4) %>%
  addWMSTiles(
    "http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cgi-bin/wms/nexrad/n0r.cgi",
    layers = "nexrad-n0r-900913",
    options = WMSTileOptions(format = "image/png", transparent = TRUE),
    attribution = "Weather data © 2012 IEM Nexrad" )
```